# How to get last child id using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 2 columns `MainID` and `ChildId`.

My table:

```
MainID                 ChildId
-------------------------------
1                      1
1                      2
1                      3
2                      1
2                      2
3                      1
4                      1
4                      2
5                      1
5                      2
5                      3
5                      4
```

I want to select only last child Id for each `MainId`:

```
MainID                 ChildId
------------------------------
1                      3
2                      2
3                      1
4                      2
5                      4
```

For this I am trying to use `Top (1)`, but its only returning one row:

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
    MainId, ChildId
FROM
    MYTABLE
ORDER BY 
    ChildId DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `top 1 with ties`

```
SELECT     TOP (1) with ties MainId, ChildId
FROM         MYTABLE
ORDER BY row_number() over (partition by MainId order by ChildId desc)
```

Also in that case you can not just order by ChildId because all values in `top` must be same. So you need `row_number`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select MainId,
       MAX(ChildId)
from MY_TABLE
group by MainId
```

Answer (score 1):

If the last child is the one with the largest id, you can do:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES MainId, ChildId
FROM MYTABLE
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MainId ORDER BY ChildId DESC);
```

There are other ways to accomplish this with subqueries -- and using window functions in `ORDER BY` is not initially intuitive.

I should note that this is SQL-Server-specific, but not because of `ROW_NUMBER()` in the `ORDER BY` clause.  SQL Server supports `TOP (n) WITH TIES`, and there is not corresponding functionality in other databases.